# FindNext returning incorrect values

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I currently have an issue with the following code. I've set up the `Find` values but `FindNext` keeps returning the wrong rows:

```
Set SearchRange = Range("B:B")
Set OpenBal = SearchRange.Find("Opening Balance")
Set EndBal = SearchRange.Find("Ending Balance")

Set CritR = Range("E" & OpenBal.Row, "E" & EndBal.Row)
Set SumR = Range("C" & OpenBal.Row, "C" & EndBal.Row)
Obrow = OpenBal.Row - 1
```

The code causing the trouble:

```
For i = 4 To lr
If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Ending Balance" Then

    If Cells(Obrow, 1).Value = "USD" Then

        abc = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritR, "OPEN", SumR)
        def = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CritR, "CXCL", SumR)
        Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = abc + def
        Cells(i + 1, 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = "OPEN/CXCL"
        Cells(i + 1, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Font.Bold = True
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Interior.Color = 65535
        Cells(i + 1, 5).Interior.Color = 65535
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "Final Balance"
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Interior.Color = 65535
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value - Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
        Cells(i + 1, 3).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Interior.Color = 65535

    End If

        Set OpenBal = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=OpenBal)
        Set EndBal = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=EndBal)
        Set CritR = Range("E" & OpenBal.Row, "E" & EndBal.Row)
        Set SumR = Range("C" & OpenBal.Row, "C" & EndBal.Row)
        Obrow = OpenBal.Row - 1
        Debug.Print "Open Balance: "; OpenBal.Row; " Ending Balance: " & EndBal.Row; " OB ROW: "; Obrow
End If

Next
```

In the debug screen, the ranges set for the Opening Balance row is wrong after the first value, its just printing the Ending balance as per below (after row 9 all the corresponding rows are actually the ending balance rows):

```
Open Balance:  9  Ending Balance: 17 OB ROW:  8 
Open Balance:  17  Ending Balance: 26 OB ROW:  16 
Open Balance:  26  Ending Balance: 33 OB ROW:  25 
Open Balance:  33  Ending Balance: 9 OB ROW:  32
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You simply cannot use [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and [Range.FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) in pairs like that. The .FindNext command looks for the next occurrence of a single find. It is completely comparable to the worksheet `Ctrl+F` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindNext()` uses the criteria from the previous `Find()`, no matter what range it operated on. But you can just call `Find()` again and specify your `After:=` parameter.

Change:

```
Set OpenBal = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=OpenBal)
Set EndBal  = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=EndBal)
```

To:

```
Set OpenBal = SearchRange.Find(what:="Opening Balance", after:=OpenBal)
Set EndBal  = SearchRange.Find(what:="Ending Balance",  after:=EndBal)
```

Comment: The check for a valid found entry would seem to be if the row returned was greater than the row previously found. e.g. if openbal.row > critr.row OK else exit for.

Comment: Wow. Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! :)